# Javascript function to open a url link

Tags: javascript, html

I am writing a javascript function to open a link to download a pdf. (The function will check for a string, if the condition satisfies it will open a link, if the condtion doesnot satisfy it will open another link).

```
<tr>
    <td align="center">
         <a href="#" onclick="openPdfReport()" style="text-decoration: none"><font size="2" color="RED"><b><u>View Report </u></b></font></a>
    </td>
</tr>


function openPdfReport()
    {
        var nameOnly = "";
                //This value s is only for testing puropse
        var s = "/testdata/e-Form/app/Eforms/Certificates/1234/abcdcertificate12345.pdf";
        var totalLength = s.length();
        if(totalLength>60)
        {
            nameOnly=s.substring(45, 60);

            String ackNoOnly = s.substring(60, s.indexOf("."));

            if(nameOnly.equalsIgnoreCase("abcdcertificate"))
            {
                window.open("http://www.abc.com/abc.pdf",'_blank');
            }
            else
            {
                window.open("http://www.abc.com/abc.xls",'_blank');
            }

        }
        else
        {
            window.open("http://www.abc.com/abc.xls",'_blank');
        }
    }
```

But when I click on the View Report link, the report is not downloading. Not able to find where i am missing. Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks and Regards

Comment: Why is this tagged as java/jsp, this is an HTML/Javascript question.

Answer (score 3):

There seems to be some Javathink leakage;

- `String ackNoOnly` should be `var ackNoOnly`
- `length` is a property not a method so `s.length;`
- `equalsIgnoreCase` is a java method, in js; `if (nameOnly.toLowerCase() === "ab..`